# How to pursue Full-time position as a teacher in any universities for teaching Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana, gita, iskcon, teaching

I'm interested in teaching and love studying Gita and similar Vedic scriptures. Is there any way to pursue a full-time position as a teacher in any universities or colleges for teaching Bhagavad Gita or similar subjects? If so can anyone help me with relevant information on how to proceed or apply? It's my dream job and my last wish is to die while giving a lecture on Gita or similar subjects and immersing myself in that knowledge

Comment: **t's my dream job and my last wish is to die while giving a lecture on Gita or similar subjects** There will be no death if you understand Gita properly.